# Can a readied action be taken after a spell is cast, but before it deals damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, readied-action, spellcasting

This question evolved from discussion in the comments from another Q/A: "[Can you use Shape Water on Tidal Wave?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154669)".

I've become unsure about how spells with a duration of "instantaneous" work. Specifically, **do their effects also happen instantaneously?**

An example where it matters:
If one readies the spell *wall of stone* and has the trigger be "when I see a *fireball* hurtling towards me I will block it with the spell", when do they actually cast the *wall of stone* spell?

We know that readied actions occur *after* their triggers, but there are (at least) two possibilities.

1. The effects of *fireball* happen instantaneously, so you could cast *wall of stone* only after *every* part of the spell, including the *fireball* exploding and dealing damage.
2. The effects of *fireball* happen in a timed order, so you could cast *wall of stone* immediately after *any* part of the spell, including the *fireball* coming towards you.

Can a readied action be triggered and taken after a spell is cast, but before it deals damage?
Or rather, which (if any) of the two interpretations above applies to spells with the duration "instantaneous"?

Comment: Related: [Do reactions interrupt their triggers or not?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117496/do-reactions-interrupt-their-triggers-or-not) and [Can you cast the Darkness spell on an in-flight arrow using the Ready action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144497/can-you-cast-the-darkness-spell-on-an-in-flight-arrow-using-the-ready-action) and [Readied actions to intercept projectiles](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/66935/readied-actions-to-intercept-projectiles).

Comment: @Rykara I feel like those last two are duplicates of my question

Comment: I'd argue the first one is very closely related but not duplicates. This one asks if the action and reaction happen simultaneously whereas the other asks if the reaction interrupts the action. The second two deal with projectiles, not spells.

Comment: @rykara Yeah I'm not exactly sure what to do. There are a *lot* of incredibly similar near-duplicate questions regarding readied actions, but I guess I should just let them sit

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Instantaneously means instantaneously

An instantaneous spell takes *no time* - by the time you realise it’s happening it already has.

The fireball shoots from the fingers, expands, deals damage and is gone *instantaneously* - your Wall of Stone is now good to go (assuming you made your Concentration check from the damage).

Now, we’re not talking instantaneously as a physicist would (except, of course a real physicist would talk about spacelike separated events synchronous from particular frames of reference), we’re talking instantaneously as in too quick to react to, like the time between a bomb detonating and you getting ripped apart by shrapnel.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98305/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-can-a-readied-action-be-taken-after-a-spell-is-ca).

Answer (score 3):

## The rules state no:

> #### Readying an Action
>
> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. [...] When the trigger occurs, you can either take your reaction **right after the trigger finishes** or ignore the trigger.

D&D does not account for things like projectile travel time or the time it takes for a spell effect to fully materialize, etc. Once an attack is made or spell is cast, it takes effect without any time interval.

---

## Rule Zero Considerations

A DM might, from time to time, bend this according to Rule Zero, but this is a slippery slope. If a spell (action) can be interrupted, why not an attack?

Many abilities have wording to the effect of "after the dice are rolled but before the results are known." Allowing reactions to interrupt actions would undermine the potency of these abilities.

It would also erode the distinction between spellcasting classes*, and tilt the advantage in a fight towards defense. In a game where combat is often already a slow affair, this would exacerbate the problem.

So, while I think there is a place for what you describe under Rule Zero, I would caution against making it a reliable homebrew rule.

<sup>*Only Sorcerers, Wizards, and Warlocks get Counterspell, which is essentially what Wall of Stone is being used to do against Fireball in your example.</sup>

Comment: If I understand this, you'd say that this has nothing to do with the word "instantaneous", that you also couldn't make a *wall of stone* is response to an arrow being fired or a javelin being thrown? Actually I think I'll ask this as its own question

Comment: Also *counterspell* does have a lesser cost (it doesn't use your action or concentration like readying *wall of stone* does) and *counterspell* completely ends the spell instead of simply changing *where* it explodes, but I see your point

Comment: @medix That's correct. *Per the rules* you could not use Wall of Stone in response to an arrow attack. Arrows (I know this is stupid) instantly travel from the attacker to the target because no travel time is considered by the rules. Once the attack roll is successful, *thwip*, the arrow has arrived. And you're absolutely right that using Wall of Stone as an ad hoc counterspell *does* carry a significant additional cost. But I'm talking more generally. There are other scenarios where the ad hoc cost may be considered equal to or less than the cost of counterspelling.

Answer (score 1):

### Mostly, no

[Dale M's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154679/can-a-readied-action-be-taken-after-a-spell-is-cast-but-before-it-deals-damage/154687#154687) is mostly right - the effect of an instantaneous spell happens instantaneously upon the completion of casting - or, as he clarifies, "instantaneously" from a game mechanics perspective, in that the completion of the spell and the application of its effects are atomic operations (cannot be broken apart or separated). Of course, as with everything, this is merely the general rule - specific rules can violate it, such as the *shield* spell (not useful in this case because *fireball* does not target AC, but useful for instantaneous spells that do target AC). There are a handful of other interrupt style spells/actions that do likewise (Paladin's Aura of the Guardian, etc). But the general rule is that being hit by an effect and suffering the effects of that, um, effect, are inseparable and uninterruptible.

### However

Things like Dexterity saves and *counterspell* work by reacting to the casting of the spell rather than the completion of it. In this way, a prepared spell can be used as a sort of counter to a spell of instantaneous duration. In this case, you would have to spend your action on your turn readying the spell (which entails casting it, but holding its energy). Then, on the enemy's turn when they begin to cast *fireball*, you can release the energy of your held spell, throwing up your wall just before the casting of the *fireball* spell is completed. To be pedantic, you could release the energy at any point of the casting of *fireball*, but in order to give the opposing caster as little time as possible to abort the spell or re-target it, you'd wait until the last possible fraction of a second.

This is risky (or at least generally sub-optimal) for a number of reasons:

- You have to anticipate the *fireball* on your turn prior to the enemy casting it. If you anticipate it too early, the spell could be wasted - though you can hold a spell for as long as you like, it requires concentration, and so limits your actions until you can release it. Anticipate too late, and well, you get a fireball to the face before you can prepare.
- Because holding a spell requires concentration, it can be disrupted between your turn and the trigger.
- It takes an action **and** a reaction to pull off, which is a worse action economy than *counterspell*
- GM fiat could work against you. Just because you waited until that last possible moment to foil the fireball's path doesn't mean that the caster doesn't get a chance to react. The GM **could** just assume the caster noticed the wall too late and the fireball is foiled as you expect, but he could give the caster a save or some other opportunity to change his mind as he notices your wall suddenly blocking his view.
- It's not a sure thing anyway (not that even *counterspell* would be either, but for different reasons). In this case, fireball goes around obstacles, so if you place the wall incorrectly (or misjudge where the fireball is targetted) it could end up being for naught, and your spell is wasted. Other factors could also contribute in the case of other spells.

The last point may be the most relevant to your question - you can't wait until the fireball is exploding to see where it was targeted before putting up your wall. This makes it a trickier proposition to properly place the wall to achieve the best effect.

Comment: Pedantically.... if you cast your wall of stone BEFORE the fireball, the caster of fireball doesn't see you, so can't target you, so he can't cast. It needs to be after the spell is cast, or the loss of visibility should mean the spell isn't castable at all (imho)

Comment: @Patrice PHB, pg 204, under "A Clear path to the Target" states "If you place an area of effect at a point that you can't see and an obstruction, such as a wall, is between you and that point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of that obstruction."

Comment: and that's me forgetting fireball isn't a target, but an AoE spell. Forget my comment then :P